# IIs rewrite rule append value to querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am trying to  make a rule for URL rewrite in IIS all day long,but none of my rules are working ..

I want to make rewrite url to transform for these types of Url

`http://localhost:2811/Search/S%2fqIMmjstZg%3d/VehicleDetails.aspx` To `http://localhost:2811/Search/VehicleDetails.aspx?mid=S%2fqIMmjstZg%3d`

`http://localhost:2811/Search/yYut%2f%2fBrHa8%3d/VehicleDetails.aspx` To 
`http://localhost:2811/Search/VehicleDetails.aspx?mid=yYut%2f%2fBrHa8%3d`

`http://localhost:2811/Search/nNLApdJeWJI%3d/VehicleDetails.aspx` To
`http://localhost:2811/Search/VehicleDetails.aspx?mid=nNLApdJeWJI%3d`

with following rewrite rules

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="QueryString">
                <match url="^Search/([_0-9a-z-%=\+\$]*)$/VehicleDetails.aspx" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="Search/VehicleDetails.aspx?mid={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

But its not working..Help Please!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong patten. I suggest you following:

```
/Search/([^/]*)/VehicleDetails.aspx$
```

Now explanation (from end)

1. /VehicleDetails.aspx$ - static text, which is on the end of string
2. ([^/]) - everything except "/"
3. /Search/- static text (you coluld try to add ^ in the begging but be careful with / after)
4. You can test your expression in IIS UI:[image]

Comment: thanks for  your solution ,it works correctly,but i have little more question about this topic..can i hide querystring in url and get value of querystring by `request.querystring["mid"]` method??For Example in above example can i hide `mid=S%2fqIMmjstZg%3d` from `http://localhost:2811/Search/VehicleDetails.aspx?mid=S%2fqIMmjstZg%3d` and get value of mid by request.querystring["mid"]???can `appendQueryString="false"` option in IIS rewrite rule help me to solve this problem???

Comment: Why want you hide querystring. If you are using Reverse proxy nobody will see it.

Comment: its my requirement so is it possible to hide with IIS rules by making certain  changes in above solution???I am not using Reverse Proxy...

Comment: Use POST instead of GET. If you hide this in get your server won`t receive this value. In POST everything except url is hidden to user.

Comment: Thanks..i am going to use get method with encryption to pass values.

Comment: Such solution can make you SEO . Btw you don't need to thanks on SO just mark response as answer our vote it up